# I can only hear Music and Blurry voices while listening songs with headphones

Tags: music, headphones, headphone-jack

I'm using Gionee P5 mini running  on Android 5.1
My nephew broke my original headphone so I bought a new headphone from market. But I can only hear music and some blurry voices when listening songs with my new headphones, I've tried few other headphones but I'm having same problme.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe much or pocket flint preventing proper contact ? Try cleaning  and using a blower to dislodge dirt

Comment: Does they sound correct when you move the connector up/down or rotate the connector? If yes, there is not proper contact of the connector and the headphone jack.

Comment: It only works properly when I loose the jack little bit

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I think you have to use the same type of headphones that came with your phone for perfect operation, or keep on trying different ones until you're lucky. This problem occurs in some phones of brands like Xiaomi etc.